# Making pair of two YUV videos (side by side) using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, yuv

I am trying to make a pair of 2 videos (side by side) with a 10px white border seperator. I used the following FFmpeg command,
`ffmpeg -i  left.yuv -i  right.yuv -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih:color=white[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w+10" left-right.YUV`
But it is not working.

Both of the videos duration and rations are same (480x270 and 8 seconds)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, (although you don't mention what's not working)

```
ffmpeg -s 480x270 -framerate 30 -i  left.yuv -s 480x270 -framerate 30 -i right.yuv \
       -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw+10:ih:color=white[l]; \
                        [l][1:v:0]hstack[v]" -map "[v]" left-right.YUV
```

Comment: i get the same error like before: `Picture size 0x0 is invalid
input.yuv: Invalid argument`

Comment: Sorry, you need to supply input params since YUV is a raw stream. Use the framerate of your input.

Comment: How i can know the bit-rate, frame-rate and ratio of a YUV video?

Comment: You don't need to know the bitrate. How are the YUVs generated?

Comment: I got all YUV raw videos from here: ftp://ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/IRCCyN_IVC_1080i_Database/1080i_Videos/
my working steps are
1. unzip  2. de-interlace  3. down sample from 1920x1080 to 960x540
4. then crop 480x270  5. make side-by-side  6. then convert to mp4.   Now i am having problem with step #5

Comment: With mp4 all those steps are easy, but i am facing problems working with YUV videos

Comment: So, in step 4, output to `.y4m` instead of `.yuv` then no need to supply input params.

Comment: how can i do that? also does it lossless? i do not want any loss before the step #5

Comment: It's the same format but with a header. Just change the extension in step 4.

Comment: yes i did and applied the earlier code to make pair
`ffmpeg -i  am_crop.y4m -i  am_crop.y4m -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih:color=white[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w+10" left-right.y4m`

it gives me the following error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c879mk9hq7n36pf/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-28%20at%205.03.33%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as an output option.

Comment: 'ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -i am_crop.y4m -i  am_crop.y4m -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih:color=white[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w+10" left-right.y4m'
It says "Option pixel_format not found."  
-------<br>
and does not work!
i used both yuv420p  and yuv422p (as my other command used 422)

Comment: As an output option !!

Comment: It works wow! But it looks  someting is wrong? because, my input+ output = 64.8+64.8 = ~130MB but the output file is 92.2MB?

Comment: i used -pix_fmt yuv422p and it looks the right size. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, may Allah (God) bless you. if i see any other problem regarding this i will come back to you.